# Laravel 5.6 - Registration Form is not working and does not show any error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

In one of my recent project, the **custom registration form** is not working. When I click on the register button, it reloads the registration form, does not print any error and no data is inserted into the database. Here is the look of the registration form:

[image]

Here is the **migration** file code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('contact');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->string('modified_by')->nullable();
        $table->string('userrole');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is the code of **User** Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'password', 'contact', 'created_by', 'userrole',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'modified_by',
];
```

Here is the code of **RegisterController**:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'lname' => $data['lname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'contact' => $data['contact'],
        'created_by' => $data['email'],
        'userrole' => Config::get('constants.ROLE_USER'),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Here is the code of **constants.php**, which is inside **config** folder:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
        'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER'
    );
```

And finally, here is the code of **register.blade.php** file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fname') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fname" value="{{ old('fname') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('fname'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('fname') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="lname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="lname" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('lname') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="lname" value="{{ old('lname') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('lname'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('lname') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="contact" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Contact No') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="contact" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contact') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="contact" value="{{ old('contact') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('contact'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('contact') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-5">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is a short clip of my problem: [Video Clips](https://bytesoft.tinytake.com/sf/MjU0NDYxNl83NjUxMTg3)

So, can anyone help me to figure out, what is the actual problem? How can I solve that problem?

- Thanks

Comment: Several things you have to change. `create` controller should have public visibility. Use `Request $request` as argument instead `array $data`.

Comment: I hope this can help you:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937459/4873251)

Comment: Found that adding @dump($errors) atop your register blade helps in figuring out what exactly the errors are. Saw this somewhere a while ago, used it and it helped me get ahead quickly.

Answer (score 9):

It may be because you have `@csrf` and not `{{ csrf_field }}` so the CSRF Token is not get posted.

Also, just for testing you can try to add this to your blade:

```
@if ($errors->any())    
    <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

You can also add this to your Controller action to see exactly what is getting posted:

```
dd(request()->all());
```

But be aware of any `Request`s that may be doing any validation on the action

Comment: In Laravel 5.6, I think @csrf is equivalent to {{ csrf_field }}.

Comment: exactly that is same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code of RegisterController:

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'lname' => $data['lname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'contact' => $data['contact'],
        'created_by' => $data['email'],
        'userrole' => Config::get('constants.ROLE_USER'),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}


 public function register(Request $request)
   {
        $validation = $this->validator($request->all());
        if ($validation->fails())  {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['errors'=>$validation->errors()->toArray()]);
        }
        else{
            $user = $this->create($request->all());
            Auth::login($user); 
            return redirect('/dashboard')->with(['message'=>'Account Successfully Created.']);
        }
   }
```

in your blade view :

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">{{ $error }}
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </p>
  @endforeach
@endif

@if (session()->has('message'))
    <p class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">{{ session('message') }}
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </p>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I agree that this is the right solution to the query above

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are returning `User::create` in your controller. You have to redirect to some page like homepage or other page.

If you have a homepage you can do like this in your controller.

```
protected function create(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $user =  User::create([
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'lname' => $data['lname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'contact' => $data['contact'],
        'created_by' => $data['email'],
        'userrole' => Config::get('constants.ROLE_USER'),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect('home')->with('message', 'User registered!');;
}
```

and get message on homepage with this code,

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: @Shimul If you have solved this problem. Please accept the answer so others will know that this question is answered already.

Comment: Thanks for your alternate solution, but it is not the actual solution I want. So far I'm happy with Laravel default flow [ Registration & than auto login ]. It was an error on validation, which by default searching for name field but I extend name as fname and lname, that's why the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

After you click the register button, if you don't want to reload the page and instead redirect you to somewhere else, and also print a message, try something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'lname' => $data['lname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'contact' => $data['contact'],
        'created_by' => $data['email'],
        'userrole' => Config::get('constants.ROLE_USER'),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    session()->flash('message', 'Thank you for registering!');

    return redirect()->home();
}
```