# Laravel Default Validaion error message not work

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am new to laravel. I want to set laravel validation on form submit. I have write below code for validation validation works but on view it does not show me any error message

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; 
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

and blow code in my register function

```
        $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'first_name' => array('required'),
        'last_name' => 'required');

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
 //            echo '<pre>';
 //            print_r($messages);
//            exit;
//            return redirect('admin/user/add')
//                            ->withErrors($validator)
//                            ->withInput();
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($messages);
    }
```

to display I have use following code in my view

```
@if ($errors->any())
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
{{ $error }}
@endforeach
@endif
```

can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: which laravel version ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are validation errors, you should use `$errors` in your view to get them. The `$errors` variable is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` and Laravel *always* makes it available to your views. You can use it like this:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="errors">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

That will output all of your validation messages (if there are any) to your view. If you want to check to see if there's an error message for a specific field, you can use the `has` method. You can then use the `first` message to retrieve the first message for that field or the `get` method to retrieve them all. An example using `first`:

```
@if ($errors->has('your_field'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('your_field') }}</div>
@endif
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#working-with-error-messages) for more information

Comment: below is my code please check and review and let me know where is the issue in my code
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;  use DB; use Session;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

Comment: $validatedData = $this->validate($request,[
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
        ]);

Comment: @ if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @ foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @ endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    @ endif

Comment: Please post your code in your question with formatting. It's very difficult to read as plain text in a comment

Comment: I have updated my question please check and let me know where i do mistake. @jonathon

Answer (score 0):

Validation messages are stored in `$errors`, which is globally passed to all views, and not in `session()->get("message")`, unless you specifically used that. With the above, you'd use

```
@if($errors->has("first_name"))
<p class="alert alert-info">{{ $errors->first("first_name") }}</p>
@endif
```

Do the same for all fields being validated and you should start seeing your error messages.

Comment: Still not working. I have use your code to display error message but not display.

Answer (score 0):

Do you override the function "showRegistrationForm"?
If Yes, you should override the function "register":

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $validation = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validation->fails())  {
        $errors = $validation->errors();
        return view('auth.register', compact('errors'));
    }
    else {
        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        Auth::login($user); 
        return redirect('/')->with(['message'=>'Account Successfully Created.']);
    }
}
```