# Avoid duplicate entries in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I need help in countering duplicate entries in laravel. Currently I am using the default laravel validator and I would like to make an alert stating if the username, email and phone number had already been registered. Thank you in advance.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10', 'unique:users,username'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
        'phone_number' => ['nullable', 'string', 'email', 'unique:users,phone_number'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'user_role' => 'user',
        'has_agreed' => 1
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Whats the actual problem here ?

Comment: Hi! When the entry has a duplicate it doesn't show any error or alert but instead simply removes the duplicated entries in the registration form. What I would like to happen is to let the user who plans to register know what happened why the registration didn't push through.

Comment: Already found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998255/laravel-5-6-registration-form-is-not-working-and-does-not-show-any-error
I am now closing this thread. Thank you

Comment: For the answer refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998255/laravel-5-6-registration-form-is-not-working-and-does-not-show-any-error

Comment: Glad to hear that.